# Is it ok to use conditional splice?

Tags: perl

Let's consider simple Perl code:

```
my @x = ( 1, 5, 9);

for my $i ( 0 .. $#x ) {
    splice( @x, $i, 1 ) if ( $x[$i] >= 5 );
}

print "@x";
```

Output is not correct, `1 9` but there must be `1`

If we run code with `-w` flag it prints warning

```
Use of uninitialized value within @x in numeric ge (>=) at splice.pl line 5.
```

So, it's not good practise to use conditional [splice](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) and better to push result in new variable?

Comment: why do you consider this to be the correct output? What would you expect for an input of `my @x = ( 1, 5, 9,1,1);`

Comment: Sorry for misprint, of course `1 9` is not correct output. Fixed the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem isn't your use of conditional `splice` per se, it's your loop. The most obvious problem, and the one that causes your warning, is that you're running off of the end of the array. `for my $i ( 0 .. $#x )` sets the iteration endpoint to `$#x` *before* the loop starts, but after you splice one or more elements out, the last index of the array will be smaller. You could fix that using a C-style `for` loop, instead of the range-style loop, but I don't recommend it — keep reading.

The next problem is that after you splice an element out of the array, you continue the loop with `$i` one higher... but because you spliced an element out of the array, the next element that you haven't seen yet is in `$x[$i]`, *not* `$x[$i+1]`. You say "Output is correct, `1 9`", but shouldn't `9` have been removed, since it's more than 5? You could fix this using `redo` after `splice` to go through the loop again without incrementing `$i`, but I don't recommend that either.

So it *is* possible to fix your loop which uses `splice` in place so that it will work correctly, but the result would be pretty complicated. Unless there's a compelling reason to do it differently, I would recommend using simply

```
@x = grep { $_ < 5 } @x;
```

There's no problem with assigning the result to the same array as the source, and there is no loop management or other housekeeping for you to do.

Comment: Re "*but the result would be pretty complicated*", A common way to simplify this is to iterate over the indexes backwards (from highest to lowest). Of course, the `grep` route is still the simplest by far.